# How to count absence days from differents shift?

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a problem when in the counting of the employee absences depending on different shifts, so all employees do not have the same shift, and what I should get is the group and the absences of this group ( the group contains some employees ),

**Groups table**

```
GroupId    GroupName
  1         Science
  2         Physics
```

**Employee table**

```
EmployeeId      GroupId
   001             1
   002             1
   003             2
   004             2
   004             2
```

**Working_days table**

```
DayId    DayName
  1       Monday
  2       Tuesday
  3        ...
```

**Timetable table**

```
TimeTableId   grouptimeId  WorkingDayId
    55eds          22           1
    e8d5s          33           2
```

****GroupTime table****

```
GroupTimeId    TimeTableId 
     1           55eds
     2           e8d5s
```

How can I get absences for every group except the holidays?

```
select groupId,(case when groupId = null then 0 else COUNT(*) end) as absence from (select groupId,
COUNT(*) as  absences1 from 
(select distinct MONTh,DAY,e.groupId
from employee_c c,holiday hl,employee e,groups,Get_Calendar_Date(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS datetime))+@Month-1, 0) ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS datetime))+@Month-1, -1))
where DATENAME(DD, Weekday) IN (select WorkingdayId+1 from timetable s,groups ds,grouptime de where dd.groupId=ds.groupId and dd.groupId = de.groupId and s.timetableId=de.timetableId and de.groupId=ds.groupdId) and  DATEPART(MM,hl.startDate)=@Month and
c.isActive=1 
except

(select Month,Day,d.departmentId from department d,Get_Calendar_Date(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS datetime))+@Month-1, 0) ,DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, CAST(DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS datetime))+@Month-1, -1)),holiday hle,employee_c c,employee e where datepart(MM,hle.startDate)=@Month and cast(Date as date) between hle.startDate and hle.endDate and c.isActive=1 and d.groupId =e.groupId and c.employeeId=e.employeeId and c.isActive=1 )) sc group by Month,Day,groupId) s group by groupId
```

Get_Calendar function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Get_Calendar_Date]
(
    @StartDate DATETIME
,   @EndDate DATETIME
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
 
RETURN
(
    SELECT  Tbl_Obj.RNo
        ,   DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate) AS [Date]
        ,   DATEPART(quarter,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Quarter]
        ,   DATEPART(dayofyear,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [DayofYear]
        ,   DATEPART(WEEK,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [WeekofYear]
        ,   DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Year]
        ,   DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Month]
        ,   DATEPART(DAY,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Day]
        ,   DATEPART(weekday,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [Weekday]
        ,   DATENAME(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [MonthName]
        ,   DATENAME(weekday,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)) AS [WeekdayName]
        ,   (RIGHT( REPLICATE('0',(4)) +
                CONVERT([VARCHAR],DATEPART(YEAR,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)),0)
                ,(4)
             )+
             RIGHT( REPLICATE('0',(2)) +
                CONVERT([VARCHAR],DATEPART(MONTH,DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate)),0)
                ,(2)
             )
            ) AS [Vintage]
 
    FROM    ( SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) AS [RNo]
              FROM sys.all_objects WITH (NOLOCK)
            ) Tbl_Obj
          
    WHERE   DATEADD(DAY,Tbl_Obj.RNo-1,@StartDate) <= @EndDate
)
```

Comment: Evolve - NO ONE should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins). And for the love of whoever must support your code - format it so that it can be easily read! In addition, using abbreviations like DD (rather than day) don't save you any effort and make your code that much more difficult to read.

Comment: It appears you have posted a duplicate question (in far better format) on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67266296/how-to-get-value-0-if-the-result-of-sql-select-except-statement-return-no-record)

Comment: Not exactly the same question, but the recent question is about no records result that I got and will help me to solve this question

Answer (score 3):

It seems like you may be going about things in a much more complicated way then they need to be. Generally for figuring out things like Holidays, Weekends, and other Date-centric Facts, a `DateDimensions` table makes things a lot simpler. There's a lot of articles out there on how to generate one, this [article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) being a good example. Once you have a `DateDimensions` table, you can join to it in a similar way to this:

```
SELECT E.GroupId, COUNT(*) AS Abscences
FROM employee AS E
INNER JOIN @tablevarDepDays AS D -- Assuming this is where you store absences?
    ON E.employeeId = D.employeeId
INNER JOIN DateDimensions AS DD
    ON D.SomeDateField = DD.[Date] -- D.SomeDateField would be your absence date
WHERE DD.IsHoliday = 0 -- Filters out Holidays
GROUP BY E.GroupId
```

Note it would be more helpful if you could please include your table schema for all your tables involved. If so, I can update my answer to be less pseudo-code like.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, I've changed `@tablevarDepDays` to another query and I've added other tables schema.

Comment: I have `Get_calendar table` that can do the same functionality as `DateDimensions`

Comment: @abdou31 thanks I'll take a look when I get a chance! A `DateDimensions` table is generally better than a function because it's reduces the amount of code to maintain, is less error prone, more readable, and mostly because it's more efficient to join to than a function (usually).